# Get WebClient errors as string

Tags: c#, web-services, webclient

I have a diagnostic tool which tests a web service.

I want the tool to report when there are problems, so I have deployed a service with a problem with the contract to test it.

When I browse to it I get a page with a very descriptive message such as:

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, 
>       whose value is:
>       System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to a WSDL 
>       export extension:
>       System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>       contract: DataContract for type XXX cannot be added to DataContractSet since type
>       XXX with the same data contract name XXX in namespace XXX is already present
>       and the contracts are not equivalent etc..

What I want is to be able to call:

```
myErrorMsg = WebClient.DownloadString("MyBadService.svc");
```

and get this useful error message as a string, however I get the following WebException:

> The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.

How can I get the same error message I received in the browser returned as a string, without getting an exception?

Thanks.

Comment: 500 error means your web site terminated unexpectedly.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

You have to catch the exception and read the response.

```
catch (WebException exception)
{
  string responseText;

  var responseStream = exception.Response?.GetResponseStream();

  if (responseStream != null)
  {
      using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
      {
         responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: This will blow up if the WebException is thrown due to a connection error, name resolution failure, etc. Check to make sure there is a repsonse before trying to get a stream from it.

Comment: Haha! finally got the solution. Thanks a lot @ccellar