# How to Get Detailed Error Message From IIS 7.5 While Consuming MVC 4 WebAPI Restful Service?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Assume I have a working Method in a Controller.  Pseudo code could be:

```
public IEnumerable<ViewMP3> MyMP3(string token, string id)
{ 
using (ControlDbContext db = new MyDbContext())
{ List<ViewMP3> list = ...some list linq statement

return list;
}}
```

I consume the WebAPI using HttpClient and no error is produced.
Now, suppose I throw an error on purpose:
    throw new ArgumentException("hello"); //inserted in method above

How can I get a real detailed error message.  All I can get is IIS 7.5 Detailed Error - 500.0 - Internal Server Error.  Note:  not to confuse the issue, I pass the error output of the WebAPI service back to the client in a string.  The error is originating inside the service but will only produce the 500.0 error.  Normally JSON is returned but when a known error condition is set, I change my code to grab the response in a string format and pass on to the client.  That is how I know what the error contains.

I have tried enabling "Send Errors to Browser".  I have changed IIS Error Pages Feature Settings to Detailed Errors.  I have changed Web.Config to include

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
```

and

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
<remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
</httpErrors> .
```

I have granted IIS_IUSRS rights to the folder with the web files.

I had a real error earlier in the day that was nearly impossible to troubleshoot because of the generic 500.0 error.  Any idea what else I could do to get detailed error messages?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036491/get-webclient-errors-as-string

Comment: Quintium, I applied the concept in the link and it worked.  That taught me a good lesson about error handling and services.  If I place the code int y = 0; int x = 0 / y; in my WebAPI Service and call it from the client, error 500 occurs.  If I wrap it in try/catch, then a Divide By Zero error returns.  That is exactly what I needed.  I guess you will post this as the answer and I accept it?  Just let me know.  Thank-you for your help!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked, Richard.

Answer from comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036491/get-webclient-errors-as-string

Comment: Oh.. looked like it added as comment.. My bad

Comment: Seems like I can't. It convert "trivial answers" as comments. So it's ok as is :)